# Flagging to close shows counter next to "flag"

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, vote-to-close

If I (as a user with vote-to-close privileges) click "flag" on a question, I see the ability to flag as "does not belong here, or is a duplicate".

- Is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)? I'm quite sure I didn't used to be able to see that.

---

Anyway, if I use that ("does not belong here, or is a duplicate") option and VtC the question, take a sip of my tea and continue about my daily business, upon submitting the "flag", the counter for the **"flag"** button gets set, not the **"close"** button.

[image]

- This would seem like a definite [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: How did you get a count next to the flag button in the first place?

Comment: @animuson: Mmmm, there isn't one until you submit the flag. Think my title was misleading; my bad.

Comment: So you opened the flag dialog, went to the close section and submitted your close vote that way (rather than immediately going through the close dialog)?

Comment: **We've all been upgraded to semi-mod status!**

Comment: @animuson: Yes...

Comment: Weirdly that's not where mods really do see flag counts.

Comment: reproduced, looking into that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in next build that rolls out (something like 2013.7.10.830).