# Number of close votes in the wrong place after voting to close

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, vote-to-close

I was marking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002724/how-can-i-select-a-part-of-a-string-in-php) as a duplicate. After doing so, I saw this:

> close | flag (4)

while the question had 4 close votes at that point.

If I manage to reproduce this, I'll try to take a screenshot.

Comment: What browser and version?

Comment: @JoshMein Firefox 25

Comment: [This again?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185869/223030)

Comment: @michaelb958 That does look like the same issue.

Comment: @Stijn did you press "flag" or "close" when you saw this behavior?  The other question, that behavior only surfaced when pressing "flag".

Comment: @psubsee2003 I have no idea I'm afraid, sorry.

Comment: I just voted to close this question using the flag link and reproduced the problem. I'm also Firefox 25, but this doesn't strike me as a browser issue. After an F5, the issue was corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix in build rev `2013.11.15.1647` on meta and `2013.11.15.1158` on sites